# Effects of IDE/Text-Editor Color Settings on our Eyes

Tags: visual-studio, emacs, ide, editor, vim

Today, we've several IDE/Editor for programming: visual studios, vim, gvim, emacs, eclipse and so on. Whatever we use, we've some color preferences for background and foreground. While most of us are satisfied with the default settings, some do customize the IDE/Editor, choose colors of their taste for various kind of label/name/text.

So I basically want to know, do the color-preferences have adverse effects on our eyes? What do you think is the best color-scheme (healthy for eyes) that one should choose for various kind of label/name/text?

My favorite color-scheme is:

```
Background : Black
Text       : White (only variables are white)
Classes    : Dodger Blue
Macros     : Pink
Interfaces : Dodger Blue (slightly dark) 
Method     : Orangish Red
Strings Literals : Scarlet Red
```

Nowadays, I'm very much concerned about this. If there are some recommendations (after some research), then please do tell me. :-)

PS: I'm not looking for personal opinions, rather recommendations with some research!

Comment: I think your eyes are the best indicator of what's good for your eyes. Do you feel fatigued and/or get a headache after spending a long time using your editor? If so, you might want to change color schemes. Otherwise, I suspect that you're fine. Aside from the report posted by Gilbert, I don't think you'll find much research here because a lot of these are subjective preferences. I find that a black-on-white scheme hurts my eyes significantly more than a white-on-black scheme does, no matter what the "experts" might say. Your preferences may vary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a 9 page pdf summary.

[The Effects of Computer Use on Eye Health and Vision](http://www.aoa.org/documents/EffectsComputerUse.pdf)

> The color of computer screen characters may also affect their ease of visibility. The
>   color of the characters can affect how the eyes focus on the screen and may bring
>   about the development of harmless, but annoying, after-images for some individuals.
>   Monochrome, or single color, displays often provide more legible images for word
>   processing or data entry/acquisition tasks. Negative contrast computer displays (dark
>   letters on a light background) generally provide a more legible image than positive
>   contrast displays (light letters on a dark background). Either black characters on a
>   white background or white characters on a black background have been found to be
>   more visible than green, yellow-orange, blue or red characters.  20

The summary consists of a lot of [hand-waving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handwaving), but the sources used to create the summary might have some recommendations based on research,

Comment: thanks for this valuable post (+1). Let me finish reading the PDF. I'll come back to this topic again.

Answer (score 0):

My schemes are as follows:

```
Background : White
Text       : Black (keywords are blue)
Classes    : Olive Green (Bold if applicable)
Macros     : Maroon 
Interfaces : Olive Green
Method     : Cadet Blue
Strings Literals : Pure red
```

You should stick to the existing scheme mate, just change Background from Black to white because white background-black letters are better than black background-white letter combination.

Comment: you said "because white background-black letters are better than black background-white letter combination"....is this your opinion?

Comment: @ nawaz: no. my friend told me this based on an experiment conducted by her. In her experiment, she let two people work on two different environment for 2 hour in a closed room (not dark,just closed to make sure only they work there). After two hour when they came out, it was always the person with Black Background-White letter extra time to cope his eyes with outside environment........She conducted this experiment on several people and all yield same result.......She did this for a newspaper because paper agency wanted to know if Black Background is better for human eyes as well as for paper

Comment: that doesn't prove that black background is bad for eye;  people who use black-background takes more time to cope his eyes with the outside environment, because he is changing the environment from black to something lighter. The same would hold true for people who use white background IF you ask them change from white-background to something darker. Let's do this experiment : ask them to enter into a darker room, and see the result!