# Anyone know of coloured code blocks?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, colors, block, codeblocks

Greenfoot is a programming environment for students to learn the basics of programming. Here's some pictures:

http://www.greenfoot.org/images/tutorials/crab-2c/edit-Crab-act.png?1345204188

http://youtu.be/u1ToiEYKwRI?t=3m10s

The IDE in action. When you type in code, sections such as methods and loops get marked in colour. This makes it visually easier to distinguish individual methods.

My question: does anybody know if this functionality is available for either code::blocks or Visual Studio 2012? I have no idea what to call this behaviour, so I can't google it. I would love to have it in my "grown-up" IDE. What I'm looking for is an IDE, or a plugin for one, that colours the regions of the code simular to the links.

Answer (score 0):

Colors are available in almost every IDE i suppose, if it's not in hole regions then the letters are colored depends in their region.

Visual Studio does this with the colored letter,and others well known IDE of course such as Eclipse and NETbeans and code::blocks does the same.

If you like especially the hole colored regions then for java you can try blueJ that has tha feature.

I think that post will be helpful for you

[Effects of IDE/Text-Editor Color Settings on our Eyes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508643/effects-of-ide-text-editor-color-settings-on-our-eyes)

Comment: That is an interesting read, but not exactly what I was looking for. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Actually i didn't understand if you just want an IDE with the colored regions or you want to build up your own IDE and you want to put that feature.

Comment: Ah. What I'm looking for is an IDE, or a plugin, that colours the regions of the code. I'll edit the question.